# Cancellation property for modules over nonabelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\Gamma$ be a nonabelian group, and let $M_1, M_2$ be modules over $\mathbb{Z}\Gamma$ (let us say finitely generated). Suppose that $M_1 \oplus\mathbb{Z}\Gamma=M_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}\Gamma$. Does it follow that $M_1=M_2$?
The case I am particularly interested in is a case where by $M_1$ and $M_2$ are one-dimensional modules.

Comment: What do you mean by one-dimensional $\mathbb Z\Gamma$-modules?

Comment: $M_1$ and $M_2$ are generated by a single element.

Comment: As a what? ${}{}{}$

Comment: As a module over $\mathbb{Z}\Gamma$.